# How to create log files using php mysql in fastest method?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to create a millions of logs using php and mysql or write to excel or to Pdf.
And i need to create this is in fastest method.

I tried the following method to insert data-

```
$cnt=200000;
 for($i=1;$i<=$cnt;$i++)
 {
   $sql="insert into logs('log_1','log_2','time'") Values('abcdefgh.$i','zyxwvu.$i');
query=mysql_query();
}
```

But its taking too much time to do the operation. Please help me if anybody know the solutions.

Comment: php has inbuild function for error log see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But actually i need to create millions of records in lowest time.

Comment: What's the engine of your table logs?

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding , you don't want the error logs ? you want to submit records in database, excel and PDF and those can be millions or billions records right ?

Comment: yes, you are correct. I want to insert millions of data fastly. If you have any solution please share that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had a similar problem months ago and there are several ways to do this, but really don't know what's the quickest:

1.- **Archive engine**: Use an engine of type archive for the table, this engine was created to store big amounts of data like logs.

2.- **MongoDB**: I do not test yet this database but i read a lot about it and it seems that works very well on this situations

3.- **Files**: I thought in this solution when i was trying to fix my problem but it was the worst of all solutions (for me at least, beacuase i need to have the data in database to make some reports, so need to create a *daemon* to parse the files and store in database)

4.- **Database Partitioning**: This solution is compatible with the first one (and even with your current engine type), just check [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) to create some partitions to your database

FYI: My current solution is Archive engine + Partitions by month

Hope it helps